# How can I move a negative number in a row up one cell and convert to a positive number, then delete negative number row?

Tags: excel, vba

I need to loop through a column to find negative numbers, then move up one cell and paste the positive version of that number.  Then I need to delete the entire row of the original negative number  The code below is what I have so far.

```
Dim ws As Worksheet

MyRange = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
Set ws = Worksheets("Sheet1")

                   'convert negative numbers to positive
For x = l To 500

If ws.Range("B" & x) < 0 Then

ws.Range("C" & x) = ws.Range("B" & x) * -1

End If

Next x
```

Comment: You can use y=abs(x) to return the +ve value.  You need to do something like so `range("b" & x).entirerow.delete`   Do you mean across one cell?

Comment: I might have made it confusing, I want to loop through a column and if I get to a negative number(ie -45567), I want to move up one cell in that row and place the positive value of that number in that cell and then delete the row that the negative number is in, then move to next negative number in that column and do the same.

Answer (score 0):

### Loop From Bottom to Top

**A Quick Fix**

```
Option Explicit

Sub test()

    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' Workbook containing this code.
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = wb.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    
    Dim LastRow As Long
    LastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
    
    Dim x As Long
    For x = LastRow To 2 Step -1
        If ws.Range("B" & x).Value < 0 Then
            ws.Range("B" & (x - 1)).Value = ws.Range("B" & x).Value * -1
            ws.Rows(x).Delete
        End If
    Next x

End Sub
```